# How to define exactly in percentage how table line will be?

Tags: html, css, resize

This is how it should be, when I reduce the window it appears like it should - 50% of the table like I specified in the CSS- but in real size, it exceeds the table and even the DIV with it is are in. (Two lines occupying 50% of an table that occupies 100% of the div).

Reducing window it seems okay:
[image: Small]
Real Size with full window (above 50% each line and it's table/div):
[image: Real Size]

Comment: Do you have a fiddle or codepen?

Comment: @JonathanChaplin It's an JSP generated page, but I will make an fiddle and post here.

Comment: If you view source and post that, it should be enough

Comment: There's not much that can be said until we see the source, except that you shouldn't try to apply styles like width or height to a tr. A tr is always as wide as the table and always as high as the tds inside.